# Determining all elements of a certain order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Determine all elements of order 4 in $Z_{20} \times Z_{14}$

I'm not sure how to go about this other than just manually checking the elements? But I feel like there must be a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(g,h)$ is an element of this group. If $g$ has order $a$ and $h$ has order $b$, what is the order of $(g,h)$? This would be the smallest $n$ such that $(ng,nh)=(0,0)$. This is given by the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$. We can see then that for $(g,h)$ to have order $4$, $g$ must have order $4$. Then $h$ can either have order $1$ or order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\in Z_{20}$ and $b \in Z_{14}$. If $|a|=m$, and $|b|=n$, then order of $(a,b)\in Z_{20} \times Z_{14}$ is $\text{lcm} (m,n)$ (why?).